# What to do if the mysql database is full？

Tags: mysql, linux, database

Please answer,thanks a lot.
When inserting data into the database, it was found that the disk was full, and the following information appeared:

The originally connected session cannot be connected to the db:

```
mysql> use music;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/mysql/socketfile/mysql.sock' (2)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server
```

Cannot connect to the database from the OS:

```
-bash-4.2$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/mysql/socketfile/mysql.sock' (13)
```

Unable to shut down the database with mysqladmin:

```
Enter password:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/mysql/socketfile/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/mysql/socketfile/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Cannot close the database with the service command:

```
-bash-4.2$ service mysql start
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/mysqldata/freelab.pid).
```

After a while I found that the mysql process was gone, but I couldn't start it with the mysql_safe command:

```
-bash-4.2$ mysqld_safe --user=mysql
2020-02-16T11:02:42.912816Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/mydiaglog/mysql-error.log'.
2020-02-16T11:02:42.955018Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /mysqldata
2020-02-16T11:02:44.479551Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mysql/mysql.pid ended

[1]-  Done                    mysqld_safe --user=mysql
[2]+  Exit 127                --user=mysql

-bash-4.2$ id
uid=997(mysql) gid=1000(mysql) groups=1000(mysql)
-bash-4.2$ ps -ef|grep mysql
root       2307   1825  0 Feb15 pts/0    00:00:00 su - mysql
mysql      2308   2307  0 Feb15 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root      19582   1844  0 05:58 pts/1    00:00:00 su - mysql
mysql     19583  19582  0 05:58 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
mysql     20707   2308  0 06:02 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
mysql     20708   2308  0 06:02 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Information in error log:

```
[root@freelab music]# tail -f /mydiaglog/mysql-error.log
/mysql/bin/mysqld(buf_page_io_complete(buf_page_t*, bool)+0xbe8) [0x2220bc8]
/mysql/bin/mysqld(fil_aio_wait(unsigned long)+0xff) [0x22dff0f]
/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0x2160850]
/mysql/bin/mysqld(std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<Runnable, void (*)(unsigned long), unsigned long> > >::_M_run()+0xa9) [0
/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0x265d64f]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e65) [0x7fc5ed7d1e65]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fc5eb90f88d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-02-16T11:00:13.978473Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

The socket file becomes:

```
[root@freelab socketfile]# ls
mysql.sock.lock
```

At that time, the pid file was not found, and no space was released when the table was deleted. After restarting the system, the database returned to normal.

In this case, if the file system cannot be expanded and the table data can be cleared to free up space, what should I do next? Is there a safer method and suggestions besides restarting?

Comment: First i say, that you should always have enough disk soace available, and it is possible with 16 TB disks and you can combi9ne multiple partitions as one, but you should run a job every hour or so that check the diskpoace and when it gets critical, sends you an email or restarts mysql or whatever is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion nbk, I understand what you mean, prevention is more than remedy. The main thing is to understand how to deal with more safe if the disk is full.

Comment: For an outsider it is hard to guess what happens with your database. It is uinceaseasing its size over time. So can  you copy some ( i mean of course a lot)  data without loosing functionality. And if you need the "historical data" you have their own routines to get them.  There are many scenarios and all have thir own strategy, sometimes it helps to use a cluster(with all problems that cost)  So take a look at your data and see hwat you need of ot on a daily basis and what is used sporadocally. I wish a i had a simple answer, but a strategy can only be defined when all the facts are clear.

Comment: Thanks,are there any cluster solutions recommended?

Comment: For that you should ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com  and as i said at the beginning you should use Raid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID and increase it periodically

Comment: Thanks nbk, but I need practical solutions, such as real and effective solutions related to this case. If you need more status information and data, I can provide it.